# https setup issue on nginx front ending apache

Tags: ssl, nginx, subdomain

I have Nginx on port 80 which handles abc.com, one.abc.com and two.abc.com.
For abc.com and one.abc.com, it redirects to Apache on port 8080.
For two.abc.com, it redirects to Apache on port 8081.

The task now is to upgrade to https.
When I install certbot on nginx, still the one.abc.com redirects to http://one.abc.com

```
Sample nginx conf:
server {
listen 80;
servername abc.com, one.abc.com;
location / {
proxysetheader X-Real-IP $remoteaddr;
proxysetheader Host $httphost;
proxypass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
}
}

server {
    listen      80;
    server_name two.abc.com;
    location / {
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   Host      $http_host;
        proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:8081;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're not listening on port 443 you don't have any certificates configured. I presume 'two.abc.com' doesn't work too?

Comment: I tried installing ssl and started listening on 443. Still https for abc.com redirects to HTTP  abc.com at 8080....same for one.abc and two.abc......but i need it to be HTTPS everywhere

Comment: Maybe time to edit the question? How is anyone going to be able to help you if your supplied config is nothing like what you're actually running?

Comment: Except for the domain names, this is exactly what I have in my nginx conf file

Comment: So you have no SSL configuration and you are not listening on port 443.  Read the Nginx documentation on the `listen` directive and the `ssl_certificate` and `ssl_certificate_key` directives.  Also, here's the [first page the Google gave me](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html) when I searched for _nginx ssl_.  Get it working with self-signed (snakeoil) certs first, then migrate to LetsEncrypt.

Comment: I have installed ssl on nginx and then Apache started throwing 402(strange) error. I had to comment all the SSL related entries then.

Comment: From [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/HTTPD/CommonHTTPStatusCodes) _402 | Payment Required | This status code is reserved for future use, currently not returned by Apache HTTPD Server._  Without the `SSL*` and `listen` directives, it's not going to work.